# Нужна ли метка [sql] в дополнение к меткам конкретных серверов?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, использование-метки

Периодически встречаю вопросы по [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), в которых есть метка [mysql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), [postgresql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql), [sql-server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) и другие метки серверов, но нет метки [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql).

Думаю, что эту метку всегда нужно добавлять в таких случаях. Прав ли я? Есть ли исключения?

Пример вопроса: [MYSQL оператор IN и несколько полей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/449647/181472)

Comment: Вот мы и вернулись к *"метаметкам"*? Думаю, на самом деле они нужны, все же  реализуют какую-то иерархию.

Comment: @avp: [tag:sql] это не метаметка.

Comment: Тогда, что такое *метаметка* (приведите примеры)?

Comment: @avp: [tag:учебное-задание], [tag:плохой-код], [tag:собеседование], [tag:программирование] и им подобные. Когда смотришь на метку и не становится ни на каплю понятнее, о чём будет вопрос.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Я считаю, нужно. Если вопрос именно по SQL (даже если по конкретному диалекту), то пусть будет. Не стоит добавлять тег [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), если вопрос по установке, найстройке СУБД или использованию СУБД из конкретного языка программирования (вроде «Читаю в Java `resultSet.getBytes()` для поля CLOB из Oracle DBMS, а возвращает ерунду, помогите»).

Answer (score 7):

Если вопрос связан с составлением запроса, то нужно, т.к. метка [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) более универсальна и охватит большую аудиторию специалистов, которые потенциально могут ответить на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

учитывая [краткое описание метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info), содержащее, в частности, фразу:

> Желательно использовать ANSI SQL запросы

добавлять эту метку лучше не стоит, т.к. это может расходиться как с изложенным в вопросе, так и с пожеланиями автора вопроса.

---

либо стоит убрать эту фразу из краткого описания.

---

а вообще, добавление метки *sql* к меткам *mysql* и тому подобным, примерно равноценно добавлению, например, метки *php* к метке *wordpress*, или, например, метки *javascript* к метке *jquery*, и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Или пересмотреть описание метки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, дополнил ответ.

Comment: А я обычно добавляю JavaScript к jQuery... разве не нужно?

Comment: не знаю. но такое добавление, по-моему, равноценно обсуждаемому.

Comment: другие не столь очевидные примеры: добавлять метку *windows* к метке *visual-studio* или *excel*, *http* к *apache* или *nginx*. наверняка можно припомнить или придумать случаи, когда в любом из предложенных мною примеров сто́ит добавлять такую очевидно вытекующую метку, но в большинстве случаев они, по-моему, не нужны.